# Keep consistent in the business entities in server and client side

Tags: angularjs, dynamicform

I'm starting to develop a web application with the follow technologies:
- Server side I'm using Java and Hibernate to define my business entities, behavior and business rules.
- Client side AngularJS
- JSON to communicate the server side and client side.

Suppose that I have a book related (id, name, isbn, category_id) with one category (id, label).

The form that allows create a new book looks like:

```
    name: <input ng-model="book.name">
    category: <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-model="book.category" data-ng-options="category.label for category in categories">
```

if I need add one more field i.e: author, I have to add it in the form manually so what I am looking for is a way to keep consistent in the business entities in server and client side. Is there any way to dynamically create a form? Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Send along some metadata about how each attribute on your model.should be rendered and create a directive that generates HTML based on this metadata.

Comment: look into angular-formly, can stop writing form controls in html, use json models instead

Comment: To clarify Nick's suggestion (which, IMO, is correct), the metadata probably needs to at least include a type; author might be a String, but `date_published` might be a Date, and `average_rating` might be a number, etc. Each of those could easily have different input types. You may also need metadata for validations (at this point it's worth considering that the problem of an auto-generated form can become a bit more complex, if you allow it.)

Comment: Yes I have been considere send the metadata but i need develop all the javascrip to interprete that metadata, so for this reason i ask if there is some like this developed